# In (the) Six Figures

Tags: definite-article, numbers

Suppose I am talking about the cost of something that is in the six-figure range:

> 1. A complete remodel has a cost in the hundreds thousands of dollars.
> 2. A complete remodel has a cost ***in six figures***.
> 3. A complete remodel has a cost ***in the six figures***.

Should it be "*in* *six figures*" or "*in* ***the*** *six figures*"?

Comment: "costs in the six figures" or "is a six-figure expense"

Answer (score 3):

The first sentence sounds wrong to me. If I were to say that in everyday speech, I would use *cost* as a verb rather than a noun, and say

> A complete remodel *costs* hundreds of thousands of dollars.

If you want *cost* to be a noun, you would either say "A cost *of* `some value`" or "A cost *in the* `range of values`. Now, in this case "Hundreds of thousands of dollars" is not a specific value, but it is still **some value**. Just like you can say "It will take me *hours* to finish!", or "Light travels *millions* of meters per second." and you're talking about an value not a range. A range would be if you say "It will take between 4 and 8 hours to finish!"

That means you could say:

> A complete remodel has a cost *of* hundreds of thousands of dollars.
>   (Vague amount)

Or

> A complete remodel has a cost in the *hundred thousand dollar **range.*** (Anywhere from 100,000 to 999,999 dollars)

With sentences 2 and 3, neither of them are correct, but they both could be correct with a minor change.

Sentence 2 should be:

> 2. A complete remodel has a cost **of** six figures.

and sentence 3 should be:

> 3. A complete remodel has a cost in the six figure **range**.

Comment: "in the hundred thousand dollar range" does NOT mean from $100,000 to 999,999.  It means $100,000 more or less (which, depending on who's listening, might be taken as approx $90k–110k, or $75k–125k, or maybe $60k–199k) but definitely less than $200k.

Comment: Oh, I guess I confused that with the six figure range.

Answer (score 0):

The first sentence will be grammatically correct if the OP omits "the" and adds "of" in the sentence as follows:

A complete remodel has a cost in hundreds of thousands of dollars.

The second sentence is grammatically correct.

The third sentence isn't grammatically correct; you shouldn't use "the" before six figures.